# How can I do code coverage on those applications compiled by unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mono

Unity3D uses C# or Unityscript as its language to program games. And it's based on `mono` to compile C# for multi-platform like android, iOS.

Now I'm tending to know how many code (lines, functions) are tested on Android. But the situation is that almost all of C# coverage tools(`NCover`,`OpenCover`, etc.) were run on Windows and they don't need to instrument code. That is the reason why I couldn't instrument them and run the application on android. 
**Is it possible to make some mono addons to instrument codes when `unity3D` compiling the C#?**
**BUT I don't know what's the way that `unity3D` calls `mono`.**

Comment: btw,recently I'm trying to use openssh to run ·monocov· on a remote android mobile.I'll update if I had any progress。

Comment: @Sayse really? I was told that unity uses mono framework to compile c#! Or how could c# run on android?

Comment: Ah apologies I got `Mono` confused with `MonoGame`